# Reading Multiple Files Parallel into a buffer

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, filesystems, buffer

Am working in a project where i have to read a set of files and put it in a buffer.The List comprises of small as well as large files.I have to read these files and for more efficiency i tried implementing it in multiple threads.Each thread will take a file from vector of file names and start reading it put it into a buffer and these buffer have to be put in a queue.I happened to have some error in program and i i don't know where exactly in my program the error occurs also don't know why ? Please help me whether there is any mistake in my logic or in my code and how to correct it. Thanks in advance

```
using namespace std;
#define MAX_THREADS 2
#define BUFFER_SIZE 8388608
vector<string>files;
deque<string>bufferq;
CRITICAL_SECTION Readlock;
int count = 0;

DWORD WINAPI ReadThread(LPVOID s);
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    HANDLE ReadT[MAX_THREADS];

    char *filelist[5];
    DWORD threadid;
    filelist[0] = "1.txt";
    filelist[1] = "cloudy.jpg";
    filelist[2] = "connectify.exe";
    filelist[3] = "VMware.exe";
    filelist[4] = "Sherlock.mp4";
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        files.push_back(filelist[i]);

    InitializeCriticalSection(&Readlock);
    long t1 = GetTickCount();
    for(int k = 0; k< MAX_THREADS; k++)
        ReadT[k] = CreateThread(NULL,0,ReadThread,NULL,NULL,&threadid);

    WaitForMultipleObjects(MAX_THREADS,ReadT,TRUE,INFINITE);
    cout << " Time Taken "<< GetTickCount()-t1 << "ms" ;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
DWORD WINAPI ReadThread(LPVOID s)
{
    long pending = 0;
    //int freespace = BUFFER_SIZE;
    char *filename = new char[50];
    char fsize[10];
    string file;
    char *buf;
    buf = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
    long filesize = 0;
    int numfiles = files.size();
    int filled = 0;
    int i = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    char* ptr;
    ptr = buf;

    while(true)
    {
        EnterCriticalSection(&Readlock);
        if(files.empty())
        {
            LeaveCriticalSection(&Readlock);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            file = files.front();
            files.erase(files.begin());
            LeaveCriticalSection(&Readlock);
        }
        bool buff_full = false;
        buf = ptr;
        int freespace = BUFFER_SIZE;
        memset(buf,0,BUFFER_SIZE);
        if(!buff_full)
        {
            if(pending == 0)
            {
                fp = fopen(file.c_str(),"rb");
                if(!fp)
                    {
                        cout<<"\nNo such file";
                        cout<<files[i];
                        system("pause");
                        return 0;
                    }
                int r1 =fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
                filesize = ftell(fp);
                int r2 =fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
                sprintf(fsize, "%ld", filesize);
                if(freespace >= (strlen(fsize) + strlen(file.c_str()) + 2))
                {
                    count++;
                    memcpy(buf, file.c_str(), strlen(file.c_str())+1);
                    freespace = freespace - strlen(file.c_str()) - 1;
                    buf += strlen(file.c_str()) + 1;
                    memcpy(buf,fsize,strlen(fsize)+1);
                    buf += strlen(fsize) + 1;
                    freespace = freespace - strlen(fsize) - 1;
                    cout<<"Files read is "<<count<<"\n";
                    if(freespace == 0)
                    {
                        buff_full = true;
                        pending = filesize;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    filled = BUFFER_SIZE - freespace;
                    fclose(fp);
                    break;
                }
                if(freespace >= filesize)
                {
                    fread(buf, 1, filesize, fp);
                    buf += filesize;
                    freespace = freespace - filesize;
                    bufferq.push_back(buf);
                    //cout << "pop"<<bufferq.size();
                    //i++;
                    if(files.empty())
                    {
                        filled = BUFFER_SIZE - freespace;
                        fclose(fp);
                        break;
                    }
                    fclose(fp);
                }
                else
                {
                    fread(buf, 1, freespace, fp);
                    bufferq.push_back(buf);
                    //cout <<"pop "<<bufferq.size();
                    buff_full = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(freespace >= pending)
                {
                    fread(buf, 1, pending, fp);
                    bufferq.push_back(buf);
                    freespace = freespace - pending;
                    pending = 0;
                    //i++;
                    if(files.empty())
                    {
                        filled = BUFFER_SIZE - freespace;
                        fclose(fp);
                        break;
                    }
                    if(freespace > 0)
                        buf += pending;
                    else
                        buff_full = true;
                    fclose(fp);
                }
                else
                {
                    fread(buf, 1, freespace, fp);
                    bufferq.push_back(buf);
                    cout << bufferq.size();
                    pending = pending - freespace;
                    buff_full = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if(buff_full)
        {
            buf = ptr;
            cout << "popping buffer " << bufferq.size();
            //bufferq.pop_back();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all you have unused variables (for example, what do you use `filename` for?). Secondly, you have a race-condition when adding to `bufferq`. Thirdly, is there a reason you use old C-style `FILE` functions instead of C++ streams?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I really dont know What race condition occured . it works quite normal for files that fit within the buffer.The error occurred only when i added a file into vector whose size happens to be bigger than the buffer. no reason there for using C stream. Will u please explain ?

Comment: For the race condition, what if multiple threads attempts to add strings to `bufferq` simultaneously? As for the problem with the buffers, I suggest you run in a debugger and step through the code line by line. And as for my comment about unused variables, the less clutter and unused code you have, the easier it is to get a better overview of what's happening, something that will help other reading your code *including* yourself in the future.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg..I tried with debugger.I found this error "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'fsize' was corrupted."I don't know really it works perfectly for files that fit within buffer and for a large file it shows error.I think the problem is in the loop i put.can u suggest changes needed ? For queue, since it s a global i have to lock and push into it rite ?

Comment: Then you write beyond the boundaries of some stack variable, possibly the `fsize` array. While stepping through the code in the debugger, keep an eye on all variables and their values. If you stop using old C-style strings and arrays, and use only C++ [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) etc., many of these problems can be avoided.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg..Ya i will look into it.I used C stream only for files not for string and vector and all.See the code i used "using namespace std" .i cut down the headers as i included string and vector classes which are c++ streams only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context that bug occurs on big files, I suppose that this line can cause problems

```
sprintf(fsize, "%ld", filesize);
```

fsize is char[10], and if filesize is >= 1,000,000,000 you'll overwrite fsize array with trailing 0. This will cause "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'fsize' was corrupted.", as you wrote. Please check the sizes of your test files.

Among others, you are filling files in loop on i, and then you wrote:

```
files.erase(files.begin());
// ...
cout<<"\nNo such file";
cout<<files[i];
```

files[i] already points to another element as you erased them, and if files are empty on the last iteration it will cause crash.

And what for are you copying file and fsize to buf if you do not copy it to the bufferq?

As bufferq is writable and is shared between threads the access to it should be protected by lock, critical section as you chose.

That's my little code review.

Comment: @Alex...Thanks now tats what i really needed.Copying file and its size is for storing the meta data . can u please tell in what way i can change my loop so that it will read large and small files efficiently and insert it to queue ?

Comment: "Copying file and its size is for storing the meta data" - nice, but you do NOT copying it to bufferq as bufferq.push_back(buf); copies buffer not from the beginning but from buf pointer, which is moved forward. These metadata are not used at all.

Change to fsize[32] for simplicity - this should fix the error with stack frame.

Comment: @Alex...Thanks a lot..But please tell me how to optimize this reading into buffer by multiple threads to achieve effective parallelism ?

Comment: That's another quite a big question! :)

Comment: Your logic is acceptable at first sight but please lock all shared writable data structures.

Also, here:   
`fread(buf, 1, freespace, fp);`
`bufferq.push_back(buf);`

don't you think that we need to prepare C-string from buf?
`fread(buf, 1, freespace-1, fp);`
`buf[freespace-1] = 0;`

Comment: @Alex...Please provide answer for that too.. why to prepare string from buf ? i mean that particular line will read file till freespace there in buffer. Assigning zero to particular position means u ending the string or what ? Also is there any other method possible to read the buffer in a parallel and returning it ? please provide any code if possible

Comment: "Assigning zero to particular position means u ending the string ...?"
Sure. See also: [C strings](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/)

Comment: The point that u insist to end string with null is perfect..But then i included the meta data in buffer and so the client on the receiving side will read the files until the size of file given in the metadata...Thanks for correcting my mistake.. Also is there any other method possible to read the buffer in a parallel and returning it ? please provide any code if possible